# gstremer not working on different machine

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer

I am using opencv with gstreamer to play a stream from a gimbal camera. I use my laptop with ubuntu 22.04 for development and the code will run on a different machine with ubuntu 22.04 also.

my gstreamer string is as follow:

```
rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.2.119:554 latency=50 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! autovideoconvert ! appsink
```

The problem is, my code works on development machine, but cannot get it work on deployment machine. below the related information about the machines are also provided.

opencv is build from the source with gstreamer plugin.

development machine:

nvidia gpu;
gstreamer version: 1.20.1;
opencv version: 4.6.0

deploy machine:

no dedicated gpu.;
gstreamer version: 1.20.1;
opencv version: 4.6.0;

**I TRIED:**
gst-launch-1.0 with debug=5 (output in comment)

edit: cannot add debug output as it was too long.

edit2: when I remove ! autovideoconvert, gst-launch-1.0 starts as intended.

**SOLVED:**

using `! videoconvert` instead of `! autovideoconvert` seems to be working on both machines. that was probably due to missing codec libraries. I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

`! videoconvert` instead of `! autovideoconvert` did the trick for me.